# Changing membership connection string

Tags: c#, .net, connection-string, sqlmembershipprovider

Iam new to asp.net membership & I need help to change its connection string programmatically.

What I have tried till now is

I have create a class project name Sample as namespace** and extends the `System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider`

code as

```
namespace Sample
{
    public class Connectionstring : SqlMembershipProvider
    {
        public override void Initialize(string name, System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection config)
        {
            string connectionString = "server=xx.xx.xx;database=db;user id=un;password=pwd";    

           // Set private property of Membership provider.  
           FieldInfo connectionStringField = GetType().BaseType
                     .GetField("_sqlConnectionString", BindingFlags.Instance |
                                                       BindingFlags.NonPublic);
           connectionStringField.SetValue(this, connectionString);
        }
    }
}
```

and altered web config file in membership tag  as

```
<membership defaultProvider="SQLMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="SQLMembershipProvider" type="sample.Connectionstring,sample" connectionStringName="SQLMembershipConnString" applicationName="@@@@@@@" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

and while running the web application project the connection string which i am changing is not get altered?

waiting for your valuable responses and comments

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need to do this?

Comment: @Alyce my job is to create users for that table and run command based on the user entering inside database

Comment: hi try this link it may be help to u http://forums.asp.net/t/997608.aspx/1/10

Comment: @AbiRuban it does not help me out

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16903988/membershipprovider-change-connection-string-in-code/16905565#16905565

Answer (score 3):

What i have also found on the net about problem is this [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/997608.aspx):

A simpler, albeit somewhat eyebrow-raising solution is just modifying
the connection string in the providers early enough in the request's
lifecycle:

```
     private void SetProviderConnectionString(string connectionString)
     {
         var connectionStringField = 
         Membership.Provider.GetType().GetField("_sqlConnectionString", 
                     BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

         if (connectionStringField != null)
             connectionStringField.SetValue(Membership.Provider, connectionString);
     }
```

Calling this method from Global.asax.cs inside
Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute does the job. Haven't tested it
too much, but even if something doesn't work, it just means it needs
to be done earlier. No guarantees this will work with future versions
of the framework, although most likely it will.

So, the 'SetProviderConnectionString' method can be called manually (after the Initialize method is finished), instead of expecting the framework to call the overwritten Initialize method when the Membership.Provider is referenced for a first time.

Answer (score 2):

You don't appear to be calling `base.Initialize` from your `Initialize` override.  I'm surprised anything works in this case.

In .NET 4 (not sure about earlier versions), you should be able to add the connection string to the configuration collection before calling `base.Initialize` as follows:

```
public override void Initialize(string name, NameValueCollection config)
{
    config["connectionString"] = ... whatever ...;
    base.Initialize(name, config);
}
```

This avoid the need to use reflection to access a private field.

Answer (score 1):

For what reason are you not using a connection string in the web config?

Typically the web server will access the database using the web server's credentials, not an individual user's credentials.

This is a generic setup guide for asp.net authentication.
http://vstudiojourney.blogspot.com/2008/06/choosing-another-database-for.html